# MSAccess: SQL WITH (NOLOCK) vs Select Distinct?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I has an Access app with multiple users. I have a task that seems to be causing an occasional collision:

1. Users are fetching data from a linked SQL Server table to their local DB, dirt simple:

   ```
   SELECT dbo_Item.*
   FROM dbo_Item
   WHERE (((dbo_Item.INVID)=4892));
   ```
2. Some of these fetches can involve 350K+ records and take >~2 minutes to complete
3. I currently have `db.QueryTimeout = 0`
4. If two users are attempting to hit the remote table at the same time, we will occasionally see a SQL/Network error.  They are NOT attempting to access the same dataset.
5. I doubt it's a timeout issue as the ERR is thrown within 1-2 minutes

The owner of the SQL Server-side data suggested adding a (NOLOCK) hint to my Access queries. I am not seeing that as an option, but I did find a random suggestion that performing a '"SELECT DISTINCT"' would not lock the table - is this true?

Any suggestions to avoid record locking issue - or ideas what else to look for?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you pulling/viewing in the results?  are you using a form/query/vba?  If no records need to be edited, then you could use a 'snapshot' dataset instead of a 'dynaset'.  In theory using the DISTINCT keyword I believe would make the recordset non-updatable, thus not use locking.

Comment: This fetch is truly a read-only result.  Can you do a snapshot on a LINKED table?

Comment: Not on the linked table directly. You can specify the DAO recordset type (dynaset or snapshot) property on a query or form via the 'property sheet'. If creating the recordset via VBA, you can specify your recordset type options when opening the recordset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to use a passthru SELECT query with (NOLOCK) applied.  Then, I created a make_table query based on the passthru SELECT query.  Seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Are they searching through 350k records or copying 350k records?

If searching through 350k records, an index on INVID may be useful.

If copying 350k record, DISTINCT could reduce this by removing duplicates, but if there are no duplicate entries, it doesn't help.

NOLOCK would help if other people were accessing the same data, essentially leaving the data open for others to modify, but your description is they are accessing different data.  If from the same table, NOLOCK could help.

Comment: They are fetching 350K records from a common linked table with >8M records.  InvID is indexed.  Yes, different subset of data from the same large Table (w/different InvIDs).  No duplicates in dbo_Item.

Comment: I added "Select distinct" as a test.  I cannot force a collision in 2 parallel sessions.  Not sure if this modification is the cause, or I am just not hitting the same collision effect.

Comment: If "select distinct" still returns 350k rows, it is useless.  I'd try adding the (NOLOCK) after the table name, so FROM dbo_item (NOLOCK).  And of course it won't misbehave while you're looking at it.  :-)

Comment: MSAccess query does not like "(NOLOCK)" at all :-(